# How can i allow other apps to act as a theme for my Android Application

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a File Manager App for Android. And i want to make it themable, so that designers can create themes for my app.
I see a similar thing in the Go SMS Pro App.

Can anyone give me a clue on how it's done.

I have seen similar questions  here but none of them were answered :(

Answer (score 0):

You can get the resources of other application by using this code

```
context.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(String appPackageName)
```