# How can I allow extensions to be made for my Android app?

Tags: android, add-on

If I'm making an Android app (such as a messaging app), and I want the app to be opened up so that other developers can make extensions (i.e. connections to other messaging sites/protocols, additional features, custom UI), what options do I have available to me to do this?

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883994/how-can-i-allow-other-apps-to-act-as-a-theme-for-my-android-application) makes it seem like if the other developer makes their own app, my app is able to pull data from it? Is this the direction I should be heading in?

I know such extensions are possible, because I've seen it with other apps, such as the file manager FX that has "add-ons" called "FX Plus" and "FX Root Access". So, basically, how can I also get add-ons/extensions for my app?

Comment: @Skynet is this an Android API that's available? so that's what I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options I am aware of:

**Intent API** can provide some functionality (You can give developers ability to send commands and data to your app). For example you can accept some kind of XML and build your UI according to it. It's slow process, but you can create some hacks to speed it up. [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

**Content provider** you can give other developers ability to work with data of your app. Databases, photos, videos. You can share your's and you can accept new ones.
[documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

**AIDL Service** never used it myself but sounds promising. [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)

Comment: Hmm... okay. Not enough info for me to really figure out what to do, but the documentation links will (at least hopefully) get me off in the direction I want to go. So thank you for the answer!